# a smart contract deploying another one

Tags: solidity

I am working on a crowdfunding ĐApp and I have a problem while deploying a smart contract from another one.

Actually, the main smart contract called `CrowdFactory` is supposed to invoke a smart contract `ClientSC` for each client, the first one returns the address of the second one, but the problem is that I don't know how to run functions of the second one with a specific address in Solidity.

here is the first smart contract

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "./sharedLib.sol";
// import "./clientSC.sol";
import "./projetSC.sol";    

contract CrowdFactory {
  using sharedLib for sharedLib.Client; 
  using sharedLib for sharedLib.Projet;

//----------------------mapping--------------------
  mapping(address => ClientSC) public usersinfo;  // contient les données des utilisateurs
  mapping (address=> sharedLib.Projet)public projectsinfo; // contient les données des projets

 //----------------------tableau d'addresse --------------------   
 address[] public users; // contient les addresse des utilisateurs (wallet)
 address[] public clients;// contient les addresse des contract crées 
 address[] public Projects; // contient les addresses des contracts des projet crées 

//----------------------Constructeur   --------------------   
constructor () public {}

//----------------------Modifier  --------------------   

//----------------------event   --------------------   
event registred(address contractAddress, address publickey, uint userId ) ;
event projectAdded(address contractAddress, address porteur, uint pID ) ;
event loggedin(address publickey , uint userId);// to see who's logged in
//²project added 

//----------------------verifier l'existance d'un utilisateur -----------------------------------------
// verifier si l'addresse de l'utilisateur existe 
function isRegistred (address _userAddress) 
  internal 
  view   
  returns(bool){
    for(uint256 i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      if(users[i] == _userAddress) return true;
      else         return false;
    }             
  }

 //----------------------Registration-----------------------------------------
 function Registration (uint _userId,  string memory _mail ,string memory _password)   
 public
 returns (ClientSC newClient )
 {
   require (!isRegistred(msg.sender));
   ClientSC newClient = new ClientSC  ( _userId, _mail , _password);
   usersinfo[msg.sender]= newClient;
   users.push(msg.sender);
   clients.push(address (newClient));
   emit registred(address(newClient),msg.sender, _userId);
   return (newClient) ;
 }
```

}

here is the second one

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./projetSC.sol";
import "./sharedLib.sol";
import "./owned.sol";
import "./crowdFactory.sol";

contract ClientSC is Owned {
  using sharedLib for sharedLib.Contribution;
  using sharedLib for sharedLib.Reward; 
  using sharedLib for sharedLib.Client;
  using sharedLib for sharedLib.Projet;

  sharedLib.Client Client; 

  address public Crowdfactory;

  uint projectsNB;
  uint contributionsNB;

  mapping (uint=> sharedLib.Projet) myProjects;
  mapping (uint => sharedLib.Contribution)  myContributions; 
  mapping (uint=> sharedLib.Reward) myRewards;

  //-----------------------------events--------------------------

  //----------------------------- modifier--------------------------

  //-----------------------------constructor--------------------------
  constructor (uint _userId,string memory _mail ,string memory _password ) public {
    //initialiser la structure client
    // ClientSC.Client.userId

    Client = sharedLib.Client({
      userId:_userId,
      mail :_mail, 
      password:_password, 
      contractAddress: address (this), 
      publickey:msg.sender 
    });

    projectsNB=0;
    contributionsNB=0;
    Crowdfactory = msg.sender;
  }

  //-----------------------------getters and setters--------------------------
  function getMyInfo () public returns (uint, string memory  , string memory, address, address,uint,uint,address) {
    return(Client.userId,
      Client.mail,
      Client.password,
      Client.contractAddress,
      Client.publickey,
      projectsNB,
      contributionsNB,
      Crowdfactory);
  }

  function getMyRewardsByContributionId(uint _id )public returns(string memory, uint){
    sharedLib.Reward memory r = myRewards[_id];
    return(r.rewardTitle, r.rewardValue );
  }

  function getMyContributionById(uint _id) public returns(string memory , uint,string memory ,uint, address, address){
    sharedLib.Contribution memory c= myContributions[_id];
    string memory rewardTitle ;
    uint  rewardValue;
    (rewardTitle, rewardValue) = getMyRewardsByContributionId( _id );
    return(c.ammount, c.tokenValue,rewardTitle, rewardValue,c.porteur,c.projet );
  }
}
```

and finally here is the shared lib from where I am getting my struct

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

library sharedLib {
  //-------------- Client-------------
  struct Client {
    uint userId; 
    string mail ;
    string password;
    address contractAddress;
    address publickey; //addresse de son wallet elle sera utilisé pour verifié sa signature 
  }

  //-------------- contribution-------------
  struct Contribution{
    string ammount ; 
    uint tokenValue ;
    Reward chosenReward;       
    address projet;
    address contributeur ;
    address porteur; 
  } 

  //-------------- Projet -------------
  //***********reward 
  struct RewardItem{
    string  itemTitle;
    uint  itemValue; // nbre de token 
    string itemDescription;
  }

  struct Reward {
    string  rewardTitle;
    RewardItem [] rewardItems;
    uint  rewardValue;                
  }
  //***********etat du projet 

  enum ProjectStatus {
    Active,
    Expired,
    Closed,
    Relanced
  }
  //***********projet
  struct Projet {
    uint pID ;
    address  porteur;
    string title;
    uint montantACollect ;
    uint montantCollect;
    uint  dateDeDebut;
    uint  dateDeFin;
    address contractAddress;
    ProjectStatus stat;
    Reward [] rewards;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format the source code.

Answer (score 0):

To run the functions on the ClientSc smart contract just call the functions on the ClientSC instance stored in usersinfo.

For example

```solidity
contract CrowdFactory {    
  function executeGetInfo (uint _userId) {
    // get the clientSC instance
    ClientSc sc = usersinfo[msg.sender];
    // you can then invoke functions on sc
    var (userId, mail, password, contractAddress, publickey, ...) = sc.getMyInfo()
  }
}
```